# How to make IE pass credentials to another site, hosted on same server?

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, iis-7, web, windows-server-2008

Here's the context:
(Internet Information Services 7.0 or so)

**Site X** is bound to **port p**, Windows Authentication enabled 
**Site Y** is bound to **port q**, Windows Authentication enabled

Let's suppose a user navigates to site X. The browser asks for credentials and the user is supplying them. Then, on one page, there's a link to site Y. The user follows the link and the browser asks for credentials again.

I know the browser is supposed to do so (because, after all, those are different web applications), but is there a way to achieve single sign-on? Sites will be accessible in Intranet only.

I suppose a way is to route requests like **http://computer:p/Y_site** to **http://computer:q**, using **Application Request Routing** as a reverse proxy (or something like that). This way, the browser may send the required headers. But then, I think the 'backing' web application won't receive the credentials, therefore cannot know the identity of the user. Or can it?

Thank you in advance!